# Django-allauth and subdomains

Tags: django, subdomain, django-allauth, django-sites

I have a website `site.com` with many subdomains (`a.site.com` ... `z.site.com`), all this subdomains are handled without using Django Sites framework.

I want to add `django-allauth` for all my domains. Now I have only one Site entry in database (domain: site.com, name: My Site). If users is in a subdomain `x.site.com` and tries to reset password or link his facebook account, will allauth use my current subdomain in redirects, callback url, restore password links etc or will it use default url from Sites framework?

I just hope that I don't have to create separate Site entry for each subdomain. Or will I have to?